# Set Command line arguments in Visual Studio 2012 c# console application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a bad day. I have a c# console application project in Visual Studio 2012 and would like to pass in command line argument when debugging.

This is straightforward in a c++ console application because there is a debug pane in the project properties. The c# console application properties does not have a debug pane.

How can I set the command line args?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t have Visual Studio 2012 anymore, but only 2013 on this machine, so you will have to believe me that it looks just the same in 2012.

If you go into the project’s properties (right click in the solution explorer on the project and choose “Properties”), then head into the “Debug” tab and there you can set the command line arguments:

[image: Command line arguments]

Just enter the arguments that should be passed when debugging the application and it should work.

Comment: My VS2010 looks exactly like my VS2013 as in the screenshot above.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a c# console application project?

Comment: @user1400716 Yes, it is.

Comment: I am definitely having a bad day. I don't have the debug pane in VS2012.

Comment: Which one do you have there instead?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project 
go to properties of the project.
hit the debug tab on it.